# COUNT DISTINCT values from multiple tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a measure that counts the distinct serial numbers from multiple tables;

```
Serial#
A
B
A
B
C
```

```
Serial#
A
D
C
D
C
```

```
B
C
D
A
```

I need my measure to be 4. There are 4 distinct Serial Numbers

I know how to make a table with the distinct values but I can't seem to create a measure that skips the step of creating an entirely new table. here is what I have tried:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES(LABOR_HOURS[Serial #]),VALUES(OIL_SAMPLES[Serial#]), VALUES(UTILIZATION[SerialNumber]))))
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
 My Measure   =
    COUNTROWS (
        DISTINCT (
            UNION (
                VALUES ( LABOR_HOURS[Serial#] ),
                VALUES ( OIL_SAMPLES[Serial#] ),
                VALUES ( UTILIZATION[SerialNumber] )
            )
        )
    )
```

Distinct returns a table, so you need to count its rows (Count function needs a column, not table).